# custum post inner page not taking single-gallery.php? it redirecting to archive page

Tags: custom-post-types, posts

```
<?php
//----------------------------------------------
//----------register and label gallery post type
//----------------------------------------------
$gallery_labels = array(
'name' => _x('Gallery', 'post type general name'),
'singular_name' => _x('Gallery', 'post type singular name'),
'add_new' => _x('Add New', 'gallery'),
'add_new_item' => __("Add New Gallery"),
'edit_item' => __("Edit Gallery"),
'new_item' => __("New Gallery"),
'view_item' => __("View Gallery"),
'search_items' => __("Search Gallery"),
'not_found' =>  __('No galleries found'),
'not_found_in_trash' => __('No galleries found in Trash'), 
'parent_item_colon' => ''

);

$gallery_args = array(
'labels' => $gallery_labels,
'public' => true,
'publicly_queryable' => true,
'show_ui' => true, 
'query_var' => true,
'rewrite' => true,
'hierarchical' => true,
'menu_position' => null,
'capability_type' => 'post',
'supports' => array('title', 'excerpt', 'editor', 'thumbnail'),
'menu_icon' => 'dashicons-vault' //16x16 png if you want an icon
 ); 

 register_post_type('gallery', $gallery_args);
 //----------------------------------------------
 //------------------------create custom taxonomy
 //----------------------------------------------
 add_action( 'init', 'jss_create_gallery_taxonomies', 0);

 function jss_create_gallery_taxonomies(){
   register_taxonomy(
    'phototype', 'gallery', 
    array(
        'hierarchical'=> true, 
        'label' => 'Photo Types',
        'singular_label' => 'Photo Type',
        'rewrite' => true
       )
  );    
}
?>

/***************************************************************/
<ul class="photo-gallery-page">
<?php
  $args = array(
           'post_type'  => 'gallery',
           'taxonomy' => 'phototype',
           'orderby' => 'name',
           'order'   => 'ASC'
       );

    $cats = get_categories($args);

   foreach($cats as $cat) {
  ?>
   <li class="stack twisted col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12 gal_pad" >
     <div id="gallery_image">
       <a href="<?php echo get_category_link( $cat->term_id ) ?>">
         <?php echo $cat->name; ?>
       </a>
     </div>
   </li>
<?php
    wp_reset_postdata();  }
  ?>
</ul>
```

Comment: Is this supposed to be single-gallery.php? What is this file?

Answer (score 0):

[get_categories()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_categories/) function retrieves the list of category objects and you're looping through categories, not the custom posts. So, The code posted here will echo category link, not the individual custom post link.

When you haven't created any custom taxonomy template, It will by default bind it to archive.php

you can have more idea about template hierarchy at: https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/template-hierarchy/

If you echo custom posts link then it would bind it to `single-gallery.php`. To create a custom taxonomy template you need to bind it to `taxonomy-{taxonomy}.php`

Hope this will help you!